# APEX Unknown statement error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am very confused :/ I am using APEX to re-create a script. For some reason it keeps throwing an 'unknown statement' error at the END; statement in the snippet of code below

```
  );


-- SKILL_GROUPS

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MASS_INSERT_SKILL_GROUPS BEFORE
  INSERT ON SKILL_GROUPS FOR EACH ROW BEGIN :NEW.SKILL_GRP_ID := SKILL_GRP_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
END;
/


INSERT 
INTO SKILL_GROUPS
  (
```

The statement before it is ended properly, and I have several other triggers in the EXACT same format that work perfectly. Anyone have any ideas why this particular END statement is having problems?

Comment: Do you receive an error when you execute the statements individually?

Comment: Nope, just ran it by itself from sql commands and it compiled no problems...

Comment: Would it be possible to have a look at the entire script and error message?

Comment: not really, a) the script is private and most importantly b) there are about 8000 lines, and the error is at about line 4700. I confuses me, because it is not throwing an error when I run it, it won run at all because it has this error as soon as it saves...

Comment: ok now I'm REALLY REALLY confused, because I just added something, COMPLETELY unrelated to this trigger, and now the error is gone. I'm happy its gone, but I still have no clue why it came or why it left. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Happy to help ;p